# Load WebView And Its Contents With The Stage At The Same Time | JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to load a WebView with its contents at the same time as the form.

For simplicity sake, this application consists of a WebView inside of a Pane. The WebView has an fx:id of webView.

I am using JavaFX 20, Java 17, and SceneBuilder 19.

Here is a simple recreation of what I tried to do:

## Main:

```
package example;
 
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("pathToFxmlFile"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxml);

        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public static void showStage(){
        Platform.runLater(()->stage.show());
    }
}
```

## Controller:

```
package example;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.web.*;

public class MyController implements Initializable{
  @FXML private WebView webView;
  private WebEngine webEngine;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){
    ChangeListener<Object> onDocChange = (obs, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){
            MyApp.showStage();
        }else if(newState == Worker.State.FAILED){
            webView.setVisible(false);
            MyApp.showStage();
        }
    };
    webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(onDocChange);
    webEngine.load("urlToSite");
  }
}
```

**Goal:** My goal is to run the `start()` method and initialize the necessary components in the JavaFX Application Thread and then wait for the loading of the WebView to finish and then call `Platform.runLater();` with `stage.show()`, since the WebView would be loaded by then.

**Result:** For a few frames, the stage will show an empty WebView or no Webview before loading the WebView.

**Question:** How do I get the WebView, with all of its contents, to show at the same time as the Stage without it loading in a blank WebView for a split second?

[image: With StageStyle.TRASNSPARENT | W/ or Without Platform.runLater | Original Opacity]
[image: With StageStyle.TRASNSPARENT | Without Platform.runLater() | Changing Opaciy]
[image: Answer]

In every variation that I tried, with or without `StageStyle`, `PlatForm.runLater();`, or `setOpacrity`, there are frames with no loaded WebView or an empty WebView (A variation of the first two images). The last image is the correct one (I cropped part of it). These images were captured via a screen recording tool and a video editor.

Comment: hmm .. can't reproduce (plain code, don't expect any difference when using fxml): webview and it's containing stage seem to appear at the same time. How do measure those intermittent "frames"?

Comment: curious: why the runlater?

Comment: @kleopatra The runLater should will the `stage.show()` on the JavaFx Application Thread. I used a recording software to see how many frames it took before the WebView showed with its contents.

Comment: yeah, I know what runlater does, thanks for the reminder :) But: the notification from the worker already happens on the fx application thread, so wondering if you had another reason for doing it.

Comment: @kleopatra I did not know that. I just wanted to make sure I was running code on the right Thread.

Comment: well, the java doc mentions it (a bit in-passing, though): _[worker's] state is observable and available to JavaFX applications and is usable from the main JavaFX Application thread_ :)

Comment: @kleopatra I will add images of the "frames" in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253537/discussion-between-monomantle-and-kleopatra).

Comment: no, I'm not the chatty type ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the stage decorator and the way that the `start()` method works, in general. A workaround to this is to set the following in MyApp:

```
stage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); //Replace stage = primaryStage with this
stage.setOpacity(0);
stage.show();
```

`StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` removes the decoration, which will, i believe, prioritize the WebView to load faster because it doesn't need to be loaded. `stage.setOpacity(0);` hides the stage while it loads in the background with `stage.show();`

and in the `Platform.runLater();` method, set the following:

```
stage.setOpacity(1);
```

This will reveal the stage along with the loaded WebView when you launch the application. I have verified it by recording myself starting the app and analyzing the recording frame-byframe to see how well it works. My results are that it loads with the frame at a 60th of a second (cannot attest for anything in-between). The previous code has about 2 frames where the WebView was not loaded. Hence, there is a very noticable difference in the two.

The downside is that you will have to make your down custom decorator.